# Error After de4dot - Application Does Not Start

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, de4dot

There is an **application** that has been **obfuscation** to learn. So in an unpack me style. In the first stage I would unpack with de4dot. **After** you unpack, the running application **stops** working.

dump and then again when I want to do the same process again stops working.

Even when I want to **fix** it with **Universal_Fix**, a result **doesn't** change.

When I look at the application with **dnSpy**, there is no problem. Codes can be read. It remains stuck in the **main** **function** when I want to run it. And it returns the following error.

[image]

That's where he hangs out.

[image]

Error returning when I want to continue.

What should I do about this?

I apologize for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed the process with a fixed version of de4dot.

Fixed version:[fixed by ivancitooz](https://board.b-at-s.info/index.php?/topic/9731-de4dot-cryptophoenixreactor-fixed-by-ivancitooz/)

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include what was wrong with de4dot and how you fixed it?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know the rules here. I found a fixed version through a site. If sharing is prohibited, please correct it.

Fixed version:[fixed by ivancitooz](https://board.b-at-s.info/index.php?/topic/9731-de4dot-cryptophoenixreactor-fixed-by-ivancitooz/)